# ajaxfileupload problemajaxFileUpload is not a function

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, ajax-upload

I am using ajaxfileupload to upload file , whenever i upload the file it gives me this error . I tried alot to fix it but no luck .

```
 TypeError: $.ajaxFileUpload is not a function  
 success: function (data, status)
```

Here is code my code .

```
            $id =$("#id").val();
    $.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "main_page/save_image_data",
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'userfile'+id,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "image_id":id},
            success: function (data, status)
            {
                if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                {
                    if(data.error != '')
                    {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }else
                    {
                        alert(data.msg);
                    }
                }
            },
            /*error: function (data, status, e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }*/
        }
    )

    return false;
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no command `$.ajaxFileUpload` in the core of jQuery.

So you are probably trying to use an external library and you have not included it in your `<head>` .

Answer (score 1):

This can be happened if you have include jquery.min.js inside your page.After remove that file problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

**add this to your file. this method is removed form upper version of jquery.**

```
jQuery.extend({
    handleError: function( s, xhr, status, e ) {
        // If a local callback was specified, fire it
        if ( s.error )
            s.error( xhr, status, e );
        // If we have some XML response text (e.g. from an AJAX call) then log it in the console
        else if(xhr.responseText)
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution-----Follow the format of the official:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var interval;

        function applyAjaxFileUpload(element) {
            $(element).AjaxFileUpload({
                action: "MyJsp.jsp",
                onChange: function(filename) {
                    // Create a span element to notify the user of an upload in progress
                    var $span = $("<span />")
                        .attr("class", $(this).attr("id"))
                        .text("Uploading")
                        .insertAfter($(this));

                    $(this).remove();

                    interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                        var text = $span.text();
                        if (text.length < 13) {
                            $span.text(text + ".");
                        } else {
                            $span.text("Uploading");
                        }
                    }, 200);
                },
                onSubmit: function(filename) {
                    // Return false here to cancel the upload
                    /*var $fileInput = $("<input />")
                        .attr({
                            type: "file",
                            name: $(this).attr("name"),
                            id: $(this).attr("id")
                        });

                    $("span." + $(this).attr("id")).replaceWith($fileInput);

                    applyAjaxFileUpload($fileInput);

                    return false;*/

                    // Return key-value pair to be sent along with the file
                    return true;
                },
                onComplete: function(filename, response) {
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                    var $span = $("span." + $(this).attr("id")).text(filename + " "),
                        $fileInput = $("<input />")
                            .attr({
                                type: "file",
                                name: $(this).attr("name"),
                                id: $(this).attr("id")
                            });

                    if (typeof(response.error) === "string") {
                        $span.replaceWith($fileInput);

                        applyAjaxFileUpload($fileInput);

                        alert(response.error);

                        return;
                    }

                    $("<a />")
                        .attr("href", "#")
                        .text("x")
                        .bind("click", function(e) {
                            $span.replaceWith($fileInput);

                            applyAjaxFileUpload($fileInput);
                        })
                        .appendTo($span);
                }
            });
        }

        applyAjaxFileUpload("#demo1");
    });

</script>
```

at least ,no more this error. And the action will receive the request